# Obfuscation options - intelilock

Tags: obfuscation, intellilock

I’m using Intellilock in order to obfuscate and lock my SW.
I tried to use “simple” obfuscation options with following params:

[image]
and when decompiling the code (using JetBrain.dot peek) I got the following code:

[image]

Since the code IS runnable  and since any idiot can understand that the second parm is the password – a breakpoint gives us the password which the SW uses in order to encrypt some files.
So I tried to check the two circled checkboxes  (public types/all parameters). When Opening JetBrain.DotPeek – the result is fantastic – nothing is understandable.
But now the SW doesn’t open at all….
When looking into windows event viewer I get the following log:
.
[image]

Which means the static main couldn’t start even…
Any simple guidlines for how to normaly obfuscate my code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So - I got a reply from IntelliLock support.

Obfuscating a public class requires obfuscating all dlls calling this class, such that all will get the new, obfuscated name.
So just adding all dlls is required.
I'm not sure yet [and will update hopefully] if skipping ignoring them will be sufficient.